# DuplexChannelFactory/DuplexClientBase constructor throws PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: wcf, uwp, .net-core, windows-10-universal

**Environment:** 

UWP application that uses the .NETCore, "Win 10 for Mobile - 10.0.10240.0"
**Scenario:** 

Tries to consume a netTcpBinding duplex wcf service.
**Description:**
Have a class derives from the DuplexChannelFactory, When I try to call its ctor(InstanceContext, Binding, EndpointAddress), the PlatformNotSupportedException thrown.
Alternatively, I tried directly "Add Service Reference" from the VS2015 reference, while using that generated client, I got the same result, stack trace is in a snapshot image, so I need to manually type partial of them here:

```
at System.ServiceModel.ReflectionExtensions.GetInterfaceMap(Type type, Type interfaceType)
 at System.ServiceModel.Description.TypeLoader.GetIOperationBehaviorAttributesFromType
 ....
 at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory'1.ReflectOnCallbackInstance
 at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory'1.CreateDescription
 at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint
 at System.ServiceModel.DuplexChannelFactory'1..ctor
 at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase'1..ctor
 at System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase'1 .. ctor(InstanceContext, Binding, EndpointAddress)
```

Comment: The error description sounds pretty self-explanatory - it doesn't support Win 10 for Mobile.   According to MSDN it supports Universal Windows Platforms since 4.5 - perhaps Win 10 for Mobile isn't part of that (but that would defeat the purpose of Universal Apps)....

Comment: And my .netframework is 4.6, while checking the .net Core assemblies built to my output bin folder, they are versioning 4.6 System.xxx assemblies as well. Assuming it behaves as advertised...